# internal Button/link click tracking application for a website

Tags: jquery, asp.net, webforms, click-tracking

The requirement is pretty simple but I'm struggling to find any application that meets it.

We have an existing ASP.NET WebForms 2.0 site.  uses the AjaxToolkit and jQuery 1.4.

The system occasionally encounters an error (big shock to you all I'm sure), and the user is asked what they did via a form.  The issue is that they usually either can't be bothered typing it out or can't remember what they did.  Additionally, sometimes, the errors occur without the user noticing (i.e. exceptions logged to the event viewer, etc.)

At the point the error occurs, we have the user's ID, along with a time, so I'm looking at a why where could retrace the user's clicks to get an idea of what they were trying to accomplish, without having to get them to attempt to replicate it themselves.

Additionally, I don't have the ability to refactor the entire site to use something like jQuery Tools.

What I was hoping was that there was some software out there already that accomplishes this, maybe by using jQuery to attach to the click events of every button on the page and logged it out (with the user's session).

The key here is that I need the exact log of buttons clicked (not pages navigated as some are ajax buttons, and postbacks), with the times, logged against a particular user.

I know there are inherit problems with the approach I'm describing, that's why I'm asking if anyone has already done it.

Comment: You could use javascript/jquery, delegate at document level a list of events to track (click, keypress, etc...) and store it in some data. This data could then be send to the server. Of course, this will have some performance repercussion on client side. BTW, you should really think about upgrading your jquery version, there is no viable reason to not do it, migrate plugins which need it. PS: sorry, this not answering your question if something like that already exists, but should not be that hard to create your own solution. Otherwise, you could see at google analytics, check it if enough

Comment: e.g of goggle analytics tracker: http://www.seomoves.org/demos/tracking-demo/